# How do I pass query parameters to the django rest api javascript client

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am working on a control panel application in which users can create memberships and logins to servers related to those membership (logins are not django user accounts, they are a separate and independent entity).

I would like to limit the list of logins returned by the django rest framework javascript api client based on the foreign key linking the login to the member table.

It seems that I should be using query parameters, but I'm not sure how to pass a query parameter to the javascript api.

Here is the javascript code I currently am working with:

```
var auth = new coreapi.auth.SessionAuthentication({
  csrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
  csrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken'
})
var client = new coreapi.Client({auth: auth});
let action = ["login", "list"];
client.action(schema, action, params).then(function(result) {
  console.log(result);
});
```

How do I tell the javascript api to pass: member_id=5 to this request?

On the django side of things:

models.py (simplified):

```
class Member(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=64)
    disk_quota = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=50000000000)

class Login(models.Model):
    member = models.ForeignKey(Member, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=254)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=64, blank=True)
```

serializers.py:

```
class MemberSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Member
        fields = '__all__'

class LoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Login
        fields = '__all__'
```

urls.py

```
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'member', views.ApiMemberViewSet, base_name = 'Member')
router.register(r'login', views.ApiLoginViewSet, base_name = 'Login')
urlpatterns = [
    path('api/docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Petal API service')),
    path('api/schema/', get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
}
```

views.py:

```
class ApiLoginViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Login.objects.filter(member=request.query_params['member_id'])
```

Comment: i suggest add a field in class "Login" with "is_login" type integerField..with values.. 1= login user, 0=No login user....and when the user is login set this field to "1" and when logout set "0"...this value you can check for validate the list login..

Comment: Thanks for the tip - I see that my question was a bit confusing and have updated the question to make clear that "logins" don't refer to django user accounts, but are a separate entity. A user might get a list of many logins when they query the database for logins related to their membership.

Answer (score 0):

The answer seems to be to use [DRF Nested Routers](https://github.com/alanjds/drf-nested-routers).

Then...

urls.py:

```
#from rest_framework import routers
from rest_framework_nested import routers

router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'member', views.ApiMemberViewSet, base_name = 'Member')
login_router = routers.NestedSimpleRouter(router, r'member', lookup='member')
login_router.register(r'login', views.ApiLoginViewSet, base_name='Login')

urlpatterns = [
    path('api/docs/', include_docs_urls(title='Petal API service')),
    path('api/schema/', get_schema_view(title='Pastebin API')),
    path('api/', include(router.urls)),
    path('api/', include(login_router.urls)),
]
```

And views.py:

```
class ApiLoginViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    permission_classes = (PetalApiPermissions,)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Login.objects.filter(member=self.kwargs['member_pk'])
```

And lastly the javascript:

```
 // Build a client.
  var auth = new coreapi.auth.SessionAuthentication({
    csrfCookieName: 'csrftoken',
    csrfHeaderName: 'X-CSRFToken'
  })
  var client = new coreapi.Client({auth: auth});
  let action = ["member", "login", "list"];
  let params = { member_pk: 4 };
  client.action(schema, action, params).then(function(result) {
    console.log(result);
  });
```